# unicode and utf8 data read from database to php/html

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

In my database i have a column of keywords. And in my column urdu language keywords is saved like this

> (Ø¶Ø±ÙˆØ±Øª  Ù„ÙˆÚˆØ±Ø²Ú©ÙˆÚ‘Ø§ Ú©Ø±Ú©Ù¹ Ø§Ù¹Ú¾Ø§Ù†...)

but when i display it in php. It gives me correct urdu keywords.

Today i imported more keywords from an ods format file now in my column keywords are saved like this

> (پلاٹ پلاٹس کنال مرلہ مرلے کنال ٹاپ سٹی خریدوفروخت ...)

so in order to display ods file keywords i have to run this query

```
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
```

From this query ods data display correctly but above not and when i run this query

```
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='unicode'");
```

above data print correctly but below not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when connect to DB

```
mysql_select_db($bd_base, $con); 
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Save all php files in *utf-8 without boom*, use notepad++ or alkepad. MS notepad save with boom and make problems.

Comment: Thank you, if You have other questions say me

Answer (score 0):

you should treat with your data by utf8 like the second option, but before this you should import your data which inserted by the default encoding to database then import again as utf8.